# не работает код создания треугольника через метод def paint_polyhon(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):

Tags: python, tkinter

Мой код

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=400, height=400)
canvas.pack()
def paint_polyhon(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
         canvas.create_polyhon(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
```

В ответ на

```
paint_polyhon(10, 10, 50, 50, 100, 100)
```

получаю пустое полотно и ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    paint_polyhon(10, 10, 50, 50, 100, 100)
  File "C:\Users\Ігор\Downloads\PYTON\Приклади файлів з 
  Пайтон\малюю трикутники\один_трикутник.py", line 6,  in paint_polyhon
    c.create_polyhon(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)
AttributeError: 'Canvas' object has no attribute 'create_polyhon'
```

Comment: Может, если исправить polyhon на polygon, то получится?

Comment: Так точно, Ваше Величество, дурак!!!

Answer (score 1):

Да потому, что у класса `canvas`, как сказано в ошибке, вообще нет метода `create_polyhon`, зато есть `create_polygon`. В следующий раз читайте внимательно ошибки и попробуйте разобраться сами, прежде чем бить тревогу :)

Comment: Вот спасибо!!!!

Comment: @Igor, если этот ответ решает вашу проблему, отметьте его как принятый (серая галочка слева).